# Display a list of integers as a String

Tags: list, flutter, dart, int

I have a list of integers like:

```
List<int> list = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

I would like to display this list inside a Text widget, having as a result:
1,2,3,4,5

What happens instead, is that it shows me the numbers inside the parenthesis:
(1,2,3,4,5)

This is my code:

```
final String textToDisplay = list.map((value) {
  String numbers = '';
  return numbers + value.toString() + ',';
}).toString()
```

and then inside the widget:

```
Text(textToDisplay);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This seems like a perfect use of `List.join`, as follows:

```
  var list = <int>[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  var textToDisplay = list.join(',');
```

Comment: This is the best solution!

Answer (score 0):

Why not just add

```
String newText = textToDisplay.substring(1,textToDisplay.length-1);
```

and use this newText?

**UPDATE:**

Consider use this instead:

```
String newList = list.toString();

print(newList.substring(1,newList.length-1));
```

Answer (score 0):

try using this  regex,

> RegExp(r'([)(]*)')

```
final String textToDisplay = list.map((value) {
      String numbers = '';
      return numbers + value.toString() ;
    }).toString().replaceAll(RegExp(r'([)(]*)'), "");
```

Output
1,2,3,4,5